# How to run multiple test classes in testng using page factory?

Tags: java, selenium

I have created two page classes to locate the elements for the two web pages (named **LoginPage.java** and **AddEmployee.java**)in one package. After that in another package i have created two test classes for the above two corresponding classes respectively(named **VerifyloginpageTest.java** and **VerifyAddEmployeeTest.java**) also i have created another class named **BrowserFactory.java** to initialize browser and create driver instance. Using the page factory I want to first run login page Test cases in their priority order and then after successfully logging into the website it should move on to the add employee web page.

**

### BrowserFactory.java

**

```
package OrangeTestCases.Helper;

public class BrowserFactory {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browsername,String url)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\int120\\Downloads\\EXE FILES\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);

        return driver;
    }
```

**

### LoginPage.java

```
package OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Pages;

    public class LoginPage{

    //  WebDriver driver;

        @FindBy(id="txtUsername")
        WebElement username;

        @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="txtPassword")
        WebElement password;

        @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="btnLogin")
        WebElement loginBtn;

        @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"spanMessage\"]")
        WebElement errormsg;

        @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"menu_dashboard_index\"]/b")
        WebElement dashboard;



    //public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    //      
    //      this.driver=driver;
    //  }
    public void typeUsername(String u_name)
    {
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(u_name);
    }

    public void typePassword(String pass)
    {
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(pass);
    }

    public void clickLogin()
    {
        loginBtn.click();
    }


    public String findErrorMsg()
    {
        String actual_error=errormsg.getText();
        return actual_error;

    }

    public boolean findDashBorad()
    {
        boolean dashboard_display=dashboard.isDisplayed();
        return dashboard_display;

    }
    }
```

**

### AddEmployee.java

```
package OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Pages;

public class AddEmployee {


    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"menu_pim_viewPimModule\"]/b")
    WebElement pim;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"menu_pim_addEmployee\"]")
    WebElement addemployee;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"firstName\"]")
    WebElement f_name;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"middleName\"]")
    WebElement m_name;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"lastName\"]")
    WebElement l_name;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"photofile\"]")
    WebElement photo;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"chkLogin\"]")
    WebElement create_chkbox;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="user_name")
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"user_password\"]")
    WebElement pswrd1;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="re_password")
    WebElement confirm_emp_pswrd;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"status\"]")
    WebElement status;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"btnSave\"]")
    WebElement save;

//  WebDriver driver;
//  
//  
//  public AddEmployee(WebDriver driver)
//  {
//      this.driver=driver;
//  }

    public void clickPIM()
    {
        pim.click();
    }

    public void clickAddEmployee()
    {
        addemployee.click();
    }

    public void typefirstname(String fname)
    {
        f_name.sendKeys(fname);
    }

    public void typemiddlename(String mname)
    {
        m_name.sendKeys(mname);
    }

    public void typelastname(String lname)
    {
        l_name.sendKeys(lname);
    }

    public void uploadPhoto(String photo1)
    {
        photo.sendKeys(photo1);
    }

    public void clickCheckbox()
    {
        create_chkbox.click();
    }

    public void typeUsername(String u_name)
    {
        username.sendKeys(u_name);
    }

    public void typePassword(String pass)
    {
        pswrd1.sendKeys(pass);
    }

    public void confirmPassword(String con_pass)
    {
        confirm_emp_pswrd.sendKeys(con_pass);
    }

    public void selectStatus(String status_test)
    {
        Select status1=new Select(status);
        status1.selectByVisibleText(status_test);
    }

    public void clickSavebtn()
    {
        save.click();
    }
    }
```

**

### VerifyloginpageTest.java

```
package OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Testcases;

import OrangeTestCases.Helper.BrowserFactory;

import OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Pages.LoginPage;

public class VerifyloginpageTest{


    String url="https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/";    
    WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome", url);

    LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
    VerifyAddEmployeeTest verify_addEmployee=new VerifyAddEmployeeTest();

//LoginPageObjects loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);


    //To verify that error message occur when username is wrong     
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void verify2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        //LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.typeUsername("adm");
        login.typePassword("admin123");
        login.clickLogin();
        String actualError=login.findErrorMsg();
        String expectedError="Invalid credentials";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualError,expectedError);
    }


    //To verify that error message occur when password is wrong     
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void verify3() throws InterruptedException
    {
       // LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.typeUsername("admin");
        login.typePassword("adm");
        login.clickLogin();
        String actualError=login.findErrorMsg();
        String expectedError="Invalid credentials";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualError,expectedError);
     }

    //To verify that error message occur both username and password are wrong
    @Test(priority=3)
    public void verify4() throws InterruptedException
    {
      //  LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.typeUsername("adm");
        login.typePassword("adm");
        login.clickLogin();
        String actualError=login.findErrorMsg();
        String expectedError="Invalid credentials";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualError,expectedError);


    }

    //To verify that error message occur both username and password are empty
    @Test(priority=4)
    public void verify5() throws InterruptedException
    {
       // LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.typeUsername("");
        login.typePassword("");
        login.clickLogin();
        String actualError=login.findErrorMsg();
        String expectedError="Username cannot be empty";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualError,expectedError);

    }

    //To verify that error message occur  password is empty
        @Test(priority=5)
        public void verify6() throws InterruptedException
        {
           // LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            login.typeUsername("admin");
            login.typePassword("");
            login.clickLogin();
            String actualError=login.findErrorMsg();
            String expectedError="Password cannot be empty";
            Assert.assertEquals(actualError,expectedError);

        }


        //To verify login is successful 
        @Test(priority=6)
        public void verifyloginpage() throws Exception {

        //login=new LoginPage( driver); 

            Thread.sleep(5000);
        login.typeUsername("Admin");
        login.typePassword("admin123");
        login.clickLogin();
        boolean actual_adminText=login.findDashBorad();
        Assert.assertTrue(actual_adminText);

        }

        @Test(priority=7)
        public void add_Employee()
        {
            verify_addEmployee.webPage(driver);
        }


    }
```

**

### VerifyAddEmployeeTest.java

**

```
package OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Testcases;

import OrangeTestCases.orangeHRM.Pages.AddEmployee;

public class VerifyAddEmployeeTest {

    AddEmployee add_emp;


    //String url="https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/";  
    //WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome", url);
//  WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.getDriver();
//  LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);


    void webPage(WebDriver driver) {
        add_emp=PageFactory.initElements(driver, AddEmployee.class);
    }


    //  to fill the registration form
    @Test
    public void verifyAddEmployeepage() {

//      login = new LoginPage(driver);

//      login.typeUsername("Admin");
//      login.typePassword("admin123");
//      login.clickLogin();
        try {

            System.out.println("value to object of driver sent successfully");

            add_emp.clickPIM();

            add_emp.clickAddEmployee();

            add_emp.typefirstname("kumar");

            add_emp.typemiddlename("sanu");

            add_emp.typelastname("Singh");

            add_emp.uploadPhoto("C:\\Users\\int120\\Desktop\\nw\\head2.png");

            add_emp.clickCheckbox();

            add_emp.typeUsername("kumar.sanu");

            add_emp.typePassword("kumar_singh123");

            add_emp.confirmPassword("kumar_singh123");

            add_emp.selectStatus("Enabled");

            add_emp.clickSavebtn();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

So when I am running VerifyloginpageTest.java class it is successfully exexcuting all 6 login test cases and logging in the website but its not executing AddEmployee page.

Comment: What is the exception u are getting? Also is the method  webPage() in AddEmp...Test class ever called?

Comment: @Grasshopper I am not getting any exception on running testcases for login page through VerifyloginpageTest.java class instead the main problem is that add_emp object is not initialized in this line....{add_emp=PageFactory.initElements(driver, AddEmployee.class);}   in VerifyAddEmployeeTest.java class...... so AddEmployee.java class is never accessed

Answer (score 0):

According to TestNG documentation You should create `testng.xml` file if it is not there and after you should configure it as you want.

Example `testng.xml` file :

```
<suite name="TestExample">

    <test name="Login">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageOfYourTest.VerifyloginpageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="AddEmployee">  
        <classes>
            <class name="packageOfYourTests.AddEmployee" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

And Output will be like below :

```
testBeforeSuite()

testBeforeTest()
testLogin()
testAfterTest()

testBeforeTest()
testAddEmployee()
testAfterTest()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make test classes run in parallel using TestNG, you should create testNG config xml file.

```
<suite name="SuiteName">
    <test name="TestName">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.your.test.class.goes.here" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please note that using Before methods you actually create a thread and it's a good practice to create new instance of your driver for each thread.

Add parallel attribute to your config file on the 'suite' tag:

```
<suite name="SuiteName" parallel='classes'>
    <test name="TestName">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.your.test.class.goes.here" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You might parallel "methods", "tests" or "instances". But since you need run classes in parallel, use appropriate value.

Now, you can also add an attribute "thread-count" on the 'suite' tag as well to set max amount of classes which will run in parallel. In case you don't specify this attribute's value, amount will be equals 5 by default.

Now it's very important: whenever you call @Before TestNG creates new thread and you need to create driver for each thread and work with it within the exact thread. For doing this, you have to put every new driver instance into ThreadLocal<> container.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> DRIVER = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return DRIVER.get();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    if (DRIVER.get() == null) {
        DRIVER.set(new FirefoxDriver());
    }
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    if (DRIVER.get() != null) {
        DRIVER.remove();
    }
}
```

Thus you will make your driver thread-safe. Also note that if you start driver in @BeforeClass, you need to driver.qiut() in @AfterClass. If start in @BeforeSuite - driver.qiut() in @AfterSuite and so on. To make sure everything works fine, you can print into your log thread id whenever you create or kill driver.

More info here:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running
https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-parallel-tests-grid-testng/